# query mongodb using c sharp in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm trying to query MongoDB database collection documents using asp.net form.
I'm getting an error - The type or namespace name 'BsonDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly?)

I looked at the similar questions posted online, but the part that I don't understand is the input required between the angled brackets - i.e DB.GetCollection. The VisualStudio context show that document type is expected.

Here is what I'm working with:

OS is Windows 2012R2
MongoDB version is 3.2.3
database name is "SignalPool"
collection name is "L1Signal_Pool_Active"

example of a document record

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58ec2e125c57ef0d142d3a35"), 
    "L1Name" : "equipment01", 
    "updatedate" : ISODate("2017-04-11T01:14:58.000+0000"), 
    "enddate" : null, 
    "timespan" : 0.0, 
    "signalname" : "MANUAL", 
    "value" : null, 
    "filter" : null, 
    "TypeID" : null, 
    "Judge" : null, 
    "Error" : null, 
    "Warning" : null
}

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;

protected void btnShowSignal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var conString = "mongodb://l92.168.2.100:27017";
            var Client = new MongoClient(conString);
            var DB = Client.GetDatabase("SignalPool");
            var collection = DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("L1Signal_Pool_Active");
            Response.Write(DB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("L1Signal_Pool_Active"));


        }
```

Comment: Is this a compiler error, or a runtime error?

Comment: You have the correct using directive for [BsonDocument](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument.htm). This leads me to believe that you do not have a reference to the correct assembly, just like the error describes. Do you have the assembly `MongoDB.Bson` referenced?

Comment: Yes, I have it ..it is shown on top of my code. I also checked in the solutions explorer in references and it is listed as MongoDB.Bson.

Comment: @Seano666 I got the error when I did "start without debugging". How do I distinguish the compile error vs runtime error?

Comment: If you right click on the project and select 'build' or 'rebuild' and get the error then it is a compiler error (ie. the compiler checked your code and there's a problem).  If you can start and run the project locally, but in the browser window you see an error printed out, that's a runtime error.

Comment: It is compile error: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'BsonDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)